# node-sass: File to import not found or unreadable: ./node_modules/

Tags: node.js, sass, pug, hexo

This is my project files/folders structure:

```
myproject/
  themes/
    mytheme/
      .node_modules/
      source/
        css/
          mytheme.sass
      _config.yml
      package.json
```

So, I modified my `myproject/themes/mytheme/source/css/mytheme.sass` file in order to import two *node_modules/* packages:

```
@import "./node_modules/minireset.css/minireset.sass"
@import "./node_modules/components-font-awesome/scss/font-awesome"
```

But when I execute `hexo server` and I navigate through my *localhost* server, I got this error message in Terminal:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ./node_modules/minireset.css/minireset.sass.
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ./node_modules/components-font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.
```

So, how should I import these packages into my main SASS file? I'm using **hexo-renderer-sass** (https://github.com/knksmith57/hexo-renderer-sass).

Regards.

Answer (score 8):

The path to your sass files has to be relative to the current sass file:

```
@import "../../node_modules/minireset.css/minireset.sass"
@import "../../node_modules/components-font-awesome/scss/font-awesome"
```